# Report viewer in php

Tags: php, sql-server-2008, reporting-services

I have managed to successfully configure a **SSRS reporting server** and connect my PHP application to render a report from it. I followed [this link](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/brian_swan/archive/2010/05/04/getting-started-with-sql-server-reporting-services-ssrs-and-php.aspx). Now what I need is a Report Viewer plugin which handles pagination , exporting etc. (exactly like report viewer control in .Net). Is there something available for PHP?

Basically I want something like the image below auto generated with every report I display using SSRS

[image: ReportViewer toolbar in .NET]

Comment: could you check if you can help me http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22259178/uncaught-soapfault-exception-wsdl-soap-error-parsing-wsdl

Answer (score 2):

I had a project at work where we had to do something similar to what you are asking.  I can't post what I did for work but I would be willing to answer questions to help you get started or if you get stuck. I haven't found anything commercial to do this. I'm assuming that your report is tabular, I don't have an answer for how to do complex reports that utilize lists, graphs, or gauges.

If you are dealing with a single tabular result, then the way that I ended up solving this is to have the report render as xml, and use xpath to parse the response from reporting service to build a custom table object. I built a custom RenderAs function that would call the RenderAsXml function and build object that defined the columns and data that goes in the table. I then used a javascript table library that takes a an xml or json structure that was built from the xml result. The table library that we used was DataTables, a jquery plugin. It allows you to pass it a json object and transform it into a table. 
[DataTables](https://datatables.net/)

Comment: could you check if you can help me http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22259178/uncaught-soapfault-exception-wsdl-soap-error-parsing-wsdl